# Delete mysql with join and limit

Tags: mysql, sql, join, limit

I have such sql-query:

```
DELETE `LINK_LA_TYP`
FROM
    `LINK_LA_TYP`
JOIN `LINK_ART` ON `LINK_LA_TYP`.LAT_LA_ID = `LINK_ART`.LA_ID
JOIN `ARTICLES` ON `LINK_ART`.LA_ART_ID = `ARTICLES`.ART_ID
WHERE
    (
        `ARTICLES`.ART_SUP_ID IN(
            10008,
            10439,
            11005,
             ...
             ...
            441
        )
    )
LIMIT 50000;
```

But i get error.... From mysql-doc i get that with delete+join+limit i will get errors....

But how can i change my code? (new to mysql and sql in all). How to change my code? To limit rows to delete....

Also in phpmyadmin i get

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'limit 50' at line 1

Comment: Your query is too long to read (and debug). Remove the irrelevant data and show us the basic structure of the query. You shouldn't have that much data hardcoded into a query anyway.

Comment: From the docs _For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used._  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i know that! give code how to solve it)

Comment: @Asad it has been edited.... but this hardcoded is not hardcoded, this is all good there.... and other ways there is not

Comment: @brabertaser1992 What's your reason for using the LIMIT anyway? You don't have an `ORDER BY` so your result may be totally unreliable.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski order by i deleted from here..... let's say order by `LINK_LA_TYP`.LA_ID, i need limit, becouse there is about 80 billion of entries.... and vps is down when try to do all in once.... wanna split in 500 000

Comment: 80 **billion** really?

Comment: @DoSparKot yes.... if you know what tecdoc is...

Comment: @brabertaser1992 Do you have an identity field in your table?

Comment: @Asad identity is "constructor" from many tables

Comment: @brabertaser1992 By "identity", I mean a field that is sequentially numbered

Comment: @Asad no... in that no: it is linking table with id's on other tables

Answer (score 2):

From the docs For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used. dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html – Michael Berkowski 2 mins ago

I concur with this. Additionally,
The DELETE command cannot have a LIMIT clause. Also, generally speaking you cannot DELETE from multiple JOINed tables.

It MIGHT be possible to rewrite the statement using a subselect something like:

```
delete from LINK_LA_TYP
where LAT_LA_ID in 
    (select LA_ID
    from LINK_ART
    join ARTICLES on ARTICLES.ART_ID = LINK_ART.LA_ART_ID
    where ARTICLES.ART_SUP_ID in (...));
```

Comment: then how to limit? if in that case i will only limit ARTICLES or LINK_ART

Comment: I stand corrected. I'm a bit old school (originally learned SQL in '94) and it seems the LIMIT clause has since been added to the DELETE statement.

As others have noted, I also would STRONGLY suggest combining it with an ORDER BY clause. Otherwise, you DELETE will end up removing an essentially random set of rows (SQL is by nature un-ordered).

Comment: how can i order when it is linking table with id's on other tables?

Comment: also non order, random is ok, one day i start deleting this 500 000 rows, then next.... untill it delete all requred data, is ok or bad?

Comment: Yup, I've had that same problem before. Using LIMIT to break a large DELETE into smaller chunks is one application where LIMIT would be used without a ORDER BY.

By the way, if the intent is to empty the ENTIRE table, you might want to look into TRUNCATE TABLE